# How to change the loaction of compressing folder for css/js in magento

Tags: magento

I am using potato compressor extension in my site to compress the css/js files. I am getting those css/js inside the media folder. But I want them in the skin folder. Is there a way to change the location of compressing folder in **potato** **compressor**.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps worked fine for me:

**1. In File Package.php:**
app/code/local/Potato/Compressor/Model/Design/Package.php

```
function getMergedJsUrl($files):
    Change:
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('media', Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure()) . $filePath . '/' . $targetFilename;
    To:
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('skin', Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure()) . $filePath . '/' . $targetFilename;

function getMergedCssUrl($files):
    Change:
    $baseMediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media', $isSecure);
    To:
    $baseMediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('skin', $isSecure);
```

**2. In File Package.php:**
    app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php

```
    Change 'media' to 'skin' at all locations.
```

**3. In File Package.php:**
    app/code/local/Potato/Compressor/Helper/Data.php

```
function getRootCachePath()
    Change:
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . self::MAIN_FOLDER;
    To:
    return Mage::getBaseDir('skin') . DS. self::MAIN_FOLDER;


function getRootCacheUrl()
    Change:
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . self::MAIN_FOLDER;
    To:
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('skin') . self::MAIN_FOLDER;
```

**NOTE** IN case if you have override the Potato/Compressor/Model/Design/Package.php then update that method with this:

**In File Package.php:**
    app/code/local/Your_Theme/Navigation/Model/Compressor/Design/Package.php

```
function getMergedJsUrl($files):
    Change:
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('media', Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure()) . $filePath . '/' . $targetFilename;
    To:
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('skin', Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure()) . $filePath . '/' . $targetFilename;

function getMergedCssUrl($files):
    Change:
    $baseMediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media', $isSecure);
    To:
    $baseMediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('skin', $isSecure);
```

Clear your magento and browser cache and js/css cache. Check the url of po_compressor file path by going to source of your site code, that will change to skin/ instead of media/

Answer (score 0):

There is a config option **Cache Directory** under **JS/CSS Compressor** settings.
It becomes visible after enabling whether **Merge JavaScript files** or **Merge CSS files** option.

There are three possible values:

- Media
- Skin
- Js